# Call function on a page from Chrome Extension on browseraction icon click

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have to call a javascript function on a visited webpage (that I know exists), from Chrome Extension browser_action icon click?

I've read through several answers related to calling page functions, but not sure I've seen any that can be invoked from icon click.

browser_action click is handled via a background.js's event handler chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener. From there I call in to a content script function via sendMessage. However in content script I do not have access to call page function, although DOM may be accessible.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Page Inspector",
  "description": "blah",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "img/icon.png",
    "name": "Click to Inspect"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "https://MYURL/*" ],
      "js": [ "content.js" ]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "inspector.js"
  ]
}
```

**background.js**

```
logOnSuccess = function () {
  console.log("inspected successfully");
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) { //Fired when User Clicks ICON
  console.log(document.title);
  /*...check the URL of the active tab against our pattern and... */
  if (tab.url.indexOf("/MYURL") != -1) { // Inspect whether the place where user clicked matches with our list of URL
    /* ...if it matches, send a message specifying a callback too */
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { text: "inspect" }, logOnSuccess);
  }
});
```

**content.js**

```
// inject the main inspector.js script in to the page
var scriptEl = document.createElement('script');
scriptEl.src = chrome.extension.getURL('inspector.js');
scriptEl.addEventListener('load', null, false);
document.head.appendChild(scriptEl);

/* Listen for messages */
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {
  /* If the received message has the expected format... */
  if (msg.text && (msg.text == "inspect")) {
    /* Call the specified callback, passing 
       the web-pages DOM content as argument */
    //alert("From Inpector : " + document.title);
    window.inspectPage();
  }
});
```

**inspector.js**

```
window.inspectPage = function () { 
$("input[FieldName='FIRSTNAME']").css("background-color", "lightblue");
    }
```

So when icon button is clicked from backgroud.js I want to be able to call the inspectPage function which is on the page (as it was injected in to the visited webpage). With the above code, I get a runtime error - inspectPage is undefined.

Anyway to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You're right, it's no way to invoke javascript function on webpage, but you can connect webpage in DOM.
(If it's yours web page you can sending message between extension and webpage with chrome.runtime functions).